# Selection and focus on element of webpage not working (offset)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

My question is a little tricky to explain, but I will try anyway. I have two horizontal tabs which, when you click on them, open a text box content. I'm trying to "focus" on them when they get clicked on. I've found a lot of material online but nothing works except for this code I'm showing below:

```
$(".accordionButton").click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(this).offset().top
    }, 500);
});
$(".accordionButtonone").click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(this).offset().top
    }, 500);
```

If I only click on the first accordionButton it works. If I click on the second accordionButton for first, it works. If I click on the first accordionButton after I've clicked on the second it works, but if I click on the second accordionButton after I click on the first it doesn't work: the focus remains at the bottom of the page. I don't know what could be the problem, I'm making some attempt with the `animate` function ([jQuery tutorial](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)) and the `offset` function ([jQuery tutorial](https://api.jquery.com/offset/)) but I would be grateful even only to know what is going wrong...

UPDATE: a partial solution is

```
 $(".accordionButton").click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(this).offset().top
    }, 500);
});
$(".accordionButtonone").click(function() {
    $('html, body').scrollTop(0);
});
```

Comment: there is no difference between your functions, you can call them with combined selectod `$(".accordionButton, .accordionButtonone").click(...)`

Comment: you should provide jsfiddle which replicates your issue

Comment: There is also an accordion effect when you click on the divs I'm talking about. It not exactly intuitive to replicate.

Comment: @softwareplay Replicate here please: http://jsfiddle.net ok?

Comment: if you want a jquery accordion why dont you just use jquery ui.

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/accordion/

Comment: I'm using exactly jquery ui to make the accordion

Comment: Can you post the html or...look at my last comment ;)

Comment: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wT6L6/) (far from understandable)

Comment: Ok, I checked it, your html tags look right. Proposal would be, you strip it down to the minimum and check that everything works then, then add the text again!?!

Comment: I've stripped the php tags http://jsfiddle.net/wT6L6/

Comment: This is the same link as before! Look below

Comment: You might want to look into [callbacks](http://www.paulirish.com/2008/sequentially-chain-your-callbacks-in-jquery-two-ways/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(".accordionButton").click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(this).nextAll('div .accordionContent').offset().top
    }, 500);
});

$(".accordionButtonone").click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(this).nextAll('div .accordionContentone').offset().top
    }, 500);
})
```

You have to put all that into a callback

```
$('.accordionContent').slideUp('normal', function(){
    $(".accordionButtonone").click(function() {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(this).nextAll('div .accordionContentone').offset().top
        }, 500);
     })
});
```

Comment: The div class= accordioContent is hidden in the beginning (when the image in accordionButton and accordionButtonone is visible instead and clickable)

Comment: Ok, for me your fiddle works (you have to set `jQuery` btw. on the left). http://jsfiddle.net/wT6L6/2/

Comment: ok this is the right fiddle then but you see, the code is there but when you click on the second accordionbutton the page doesn't focus on the firts part of the content inside it.. (don't know if it's clear)...

Comment: it is more specific than mine, but the problem for the second accordion div remains. I've partially solved the situation writing: $('html, body').scrollTop(0); in the second onclick function, the one of the accordionButtonone. I don't know how to go on, but at least it is not staying in the footer of the page. I'm updating my question

Comment: Ok, I see, the thing is, you have no content, when the first accordion is open and then you click the second. You want to look into that? You need to set the `.click` function into the callback of the `slideUp()`. So **after** the `slideUp()` the `offset()` of the `div` is calculated!

Comment: Look at the callback I provided, gotta go bye

Answer (score 0):

The solution is NOT elegant, but it works:

```
$(".accordionButton").click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(this).offset().top
    }, 10);
});
$(".accordionButtonone").click(function() {
    $('html, body').scrollTop(458);

});
```

Answer (score -1):

You are making it scroll down by using offset. remove the offset and it will stop scrolling down. also, instead of using individual selectors, why don't you write some code that utilizes jquery's 'this'

```
$(this)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "remove the offset"? i couldn't find anything about this operation online and i'm not so good in jQuery to improvise

Comment: you mean that i should take away $('html, body') and write $(this) instead?

Comment: lets start over here. you need an accordion right? then use jquery UI, with the documented html markup, and you would call it like this:

$('.ELEMENTNAME').accordion();

http://jqueryui.com/accordion/

Comment: The accordion is working, why should i start over? Even the focus is working if i click in one order, it's just in the other way that it is not working, it is a problem of css i assume ,i should remove the offset but i don't know how to remove it!

Comment: $(".accordionButton").click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate();
});
$(".accordionButtonone").click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate();